# Customize Silverstripe Login Form

Tags: silverstripe

I have password protected my whole Silverstripe site and now I need to customize the form fields for the login screen. Where can I find where this is happening? Another problem I would have is: I want to show the custom login screen to anyone not trying to access `http://example.com/admin` (meaning, show the default login screen if an admin is trying to login, else show the custom one).

I'm using the latest version of Silverstripe (2.4.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

might need this too in a future project, so i did some research and found these:
http://tamethebackbutton.blogspot.com/2009/09/customize-your-own-silverstripe-login.html
might work for you too?

Comment: Would you mind adding some relevant detail from the link in case it dies at some point?